# Decorator hide method description

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

When I put a class method under a decorator it hides the method description ("""x""") in help(class_name).
How can I fix that please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
def decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args):
        # do something
    return wrapped
```

Comment: Nice, never heard of this!